# Evaluating $\int_0^{\pi } \frac{\sin (n \sigma )}{(a-\cos \sigma )^2} \, d\sigma$

Tags: integration, trigonometric-integrals

What is the formula for $$\int_0^{\pi } \frac{\sin (n \sigma )}{(a-\cos \sigma )^2} \, d\sigma$$
where $ a>1 $ and $n$ is a positive integer?

To evaluate, I tried to replace $a$ with $\cosh\xi $ in the integral

$$\int_0^{\pi } \frac{\sin (n \sigma )}{(\cosh\xi-\cos \sigma )^2} \, d\sigma$$

Please note that I already obtained the formula for  a related integral $$\int_0^{\pi } \frac{\cos (n \sigma )}{(a-\cos \sigma )^2} \, d\sigma
= \frac{\pi(n \sqrt{a^2-1}+a)}{(a^2-1)^{3/2} (\sqrt{a^2-1}+a)^n}
$$

Comment: What is your formula for $\int_0^{\pi } \frac{\cos (n \sigma )}{(a-\cos (\sigma ))^2} \, d\sigma$ ?

Comment: The following is reduced from a formula in Gradshteyn and Ryzhik.

$\int_0^{\pi } \frac{\cos (n \sigma )}{(a-\cos (\sigma ))^2} \, d\sigma =\frac{\pi  \left(n\sqrt{a^2-1} +a\right)}{\left(a^2-1\right)^{3/2} \left(\sqrt{a^2-1}+a\right)^n}$

Comment: In fact I just put  $\cosh (\xi )$  as $a$ in my original integral $\int_0^{\pi } \frac{\sin (n \sigma )}{(\cosh (\xi )-\cos (\sigma ))^2} \, d\sigma$

Comment: An approach for particular $n$ would be to use that $\sin n \theta = U_{n - 1}(\cos \theta) \sin \theta$, where $U_{n - 1}$ is the $(n - 1)$st Chebyshev polynomial of the second kind, then substitute $u = \cos \theta$ to transform the integral into a rational one, $\int_{-1}^1 \frac{U_{n - 1}(u) \,du}{(u - a)^2}$. There are hypergeometric representations for general $U_m$, though I don't know whether they'd be helpful here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Evaluate
\begin{align}
K_n(r)= &\int_0^\pi \frac{e^{i n x}}{1-2r\cos x+r^2} \overset{z= e^{ix} }{dx}
= \frac1i \int_\gamma\frac{z^n}{(z-r)( 1-rz)}dz\\
\end{align}
along the semicircle path $\gamma$ in the upper plane, resulting in
\begin{align}
I_n(r) =& \int_0^\pi \frac{\cos (n x)}{1-2r \cos x +r^2}dx=\Re K_n(r) = \frac{\pi r^n}{1-r^2}\\
J_n(r)= &\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin (n x)}{1-2r \cos x +r^2}dx= \Im K_n(r)\\
=&\ \frac{{r^{-n}}-r^n} {1-r^2}\ln\frac{1+r}{1-r}
-2\sum_{k=1}^{[\frac n2]}\frac{{r^{-n-1+2k}}-r^{n+1-2k}}{(2k-1)(1-r^2)}
\end{align}
Then, utilize $I_n(r)$ and $J_n(r)$ to evaluate
\begin{align}
& \int_0^\pi \frac{\cos (n x)}{\cosh\xi -\cos x }dx
=2e^{-\xi} I_n(e^{-\xi})=\frac{\pi e^{-n\xi}}{\sinh \xi}\\
\\
&\int_0^\pi \frac{\sin( n x)}{\cosh\xi-\cos x }dx
= 2e^{-\xi} J_n(e^{-\xi})\\
=& \ \frac{2\sinh(n\xi)}{\sinh \xi} \ln\left(\coth\frac\xi2\right)
-4\sum_{k=1}^{[\frac n2]}\frac{\sinh(n+1-2k)\xi}{(2k-1)\sinh\xi}
\end{align}
which, via differentiation with respect to $\xi$, lead to
\begin{align}
& \int_0^\pi \frac{\cos (n x)}{(\cosh\xi -\cos x )^2}dx=\frac{\pi e^{-n\xi} (n+\coth\xi )}{\sinh^2 \xi}\\
\\
 & \int_0^\pi \frac{\sin (n x)}{(\cosh\xi -\cos x )^2}dx\\
=& \ \frac{2}{\sinh^2 \xi}\bigg\{ \sin^2\frac{n\pi}2
 + \left[\frac{\sinh(n\xi)}{\tanh\xi}-n\cosh(n\xi) \right]\ln\left(\coth\frac\xi2\right)\\
&\hspace{5mm} -\sum_{k=1}^{[\frac n2]}\frac{2}{2k-1}
\left[\frac{\sinh(n+1-2k)\xi}{\tanh\xi} -n\cosh(n+1-2k)\xi\right]\bigg\}
\end{align}

Comment: Thank you so much. With some trigonometric identities I could get an expression in terms of Lerch Function (Mathematica did the final form), but your finite sum is really wonderful.